# Attaching multiple rigged objects to the body

Tags: rigging, parent

[Project I need help with (DeviantArt download)](https://www.deviantart.com/weeb-dork-trash/art/TruffleAThief-HElP-888323020?ga_submit_new=10%3A1628548294)
[image: TruffleAThief]

Modeling the "paperwork" in Blender from the concept art:
[image: modeling process]

(My period key doesn't work so please forgive the run-on sentences)

Hi there! I've always hated rigging because it can get incredibly confusing, but that's why I'm still working on it! However, I've come across an issue where my character's clothing armature (along with tail and ears) won't move around with the rest of the body, even though I have the body armature parented to them.

I've even tried using the 'child of' constraint, but when I go into pose mode, it doesn't work.

I would like to point out that the armatures are all completely separate armatures and the meshes are all separate too that I'm trying to parent to the body so they move around together. Separately they work just fine! (Save for some weight paint troubles with the cape-)

Edit: Still not fixed but I've realized I still have so much to fix in terms of weight painting...

Comment: Hello and welcome. I've just checked your blend file. There are only several planes in it and the "concept/reference/texture" image. Is Truffle delivered in parts and do we have to assemble it ourselves? ;-)  Seriously, is this the correct blend file? There is no armature.

Comment: I've given it a try and puzzled this rouge cat together. Although, I have no idea how the cape+hood should work. But I wonder why do you need multiple armatures? Do you want to animate some foldings, too?

Comment: Hi! I only have one blend file for this lil man but I can try again in case I forgot to save before sending out this! Make sure that things aren't hidden, as there are 3 collections, one for a base spread, one with the colored image, and then one with the built together version. I used multiple armatures to make it easier to put things together. If there's a way to join everything together without ruining the weight paint I'd love to know! (I'm very sorry about you putting him together- I know quite a bit bout modeling but this still took quite a while to put together myself woops)

Comment: (The main file was updated! Hopefully that'll fix the missing armature!)

Comment: Oh, you posted 2 comments, I missed the first one... so, I've just double-checked the downloaded blend file and added a screenshot of it to your question. But I have to say sorry, there is only one collection. The greyscale reference is new. That was missing yesterday. I've used the colored image to create my own version: https://pasteall.org/pic/de77678f276d474ba0a17451fff3e29e but I still have no idea how you made that cape or how and why you create the armatures. Could you upload it again?

Comment: You did a great job piecing the parts together! For a lot of what I did I created edge loops to make curved parts, for the cape what I did was mirror one piece and then scrap half of the smaller piece to make a triangle that I fitted to the back of the cape woops. I'm about to update the deviantart thing again, I saved it as a completely different .blend this time- crossing fingers!

Comment: Your last upload worked. I got him up and running and will post an answer later. Here is a teaser ;-) https://imgur.com/a/nyNPbeR

Comment: He looks so goofy in the most charming way! Thank you so much and I look forward for the answer to my problem! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @Blunder Hey there! I don't intend to rush you or anything, just a friendly reminder in case you forgot! (Please take your time, again I just want to remind you that I'm still here!)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the friendly reminder. I'm glad you're still here :-) I've written it down but it took longer than I thought. There was still an issue with the parent relationship. It's fixed now, except for the root bone of the model. I'll need to examine this closer. I think there is something wrong with the IK. It causes flickering/jumping while the animation runs. Weird. Just in case you get lost or I forgot something I've uploaded the blend file and attached it to the answer. It's the previous version that doesn't have the root bone and no glitches. Have fun. Truffle is a cool cat :D

Comment: Ok, it's a bad idea to make the IK bones a child of the root bone. This causes the flickering. (I still wonder why this works with the cape?) A question to you: Why are the *foot* bones children of the *LegIK* bones but not of the *Leg* bones? (see screenshot 3 of in the answer). And why is the *Chain Length* of the IK constraint 2 for the legs but 0 for the arms? I'm not an IK expert but shouldn't they be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did a great job with the separate rigs. All you need to do is to merge them, with exception of the cape and the knife. Then fix the weights, and give the knife a *Child Of* constraint so Truffle can pick it up.

### Body Rig

Armature objects can be joined like mesh objects with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>. Then you can parent the bones to get the bone mechanics working.

- in *Object* mode, select the *tail* and the *body* armature. Make the *body* armature the parent by selecting it last (=active object). Then join them <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>.
- switch to *Edit* mode, select the *very first tail* bone, then the *body* bone, and parent them <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, with *Keep Offset* (note: *Connected* would pin it to the neck)
  [image: attaching the tail]
  <sup>attaching the tail</sup>
- do the same with both *ears* and the *head* bone:
  [image: attaching the ears]
  <sup>attaching the ears</sup>
- consider adding a **root bone** for the body rig and parent all deformation bones to it (but not the IK bones which cause flickering during animation). This allows you to move around the character in *Pose* mode without the IK effect. If you (ab)use the *body* bone as *root* bone and move the character then it looks like he is being dragged away. The arms and legs try to stay in place and are dragged behind the body if the distance gets bigger.
- don't forget to **uncheck** the `[_]` *Deform* checkbox for the root bone!
- The final bone hierarchy looks like this:
  [image: root bone]
- check the ears, belt, and potions. They need to be parented to the *Body Rig*. This can be done *With Empty Group* and you can create and assign the vertices of the mesh to the specific bone groups. Ears need to be assigned to the *Head* vertex group, belt, and potions to the *Body* group. Create the group if it's not present. Check if all items have the *Armature* modifier on the stack.

### Cape Rig

My first idea was to merge the cape, too. But on second thought it might be better to keep it separated. This makes it possible to take off the cape or give it to another character.

- in *Edit* mode, add a **root bone** to the cape
- decrease the IK *Chain Length* from 4 to `3`
- then make the root a parent for the IK bones and the 4 deformation bones:
  [image: cape rig]
- the root bone is a deformation bone, you might want to add more deformation bones to control the front of the hood and the sides of the hood because the back of the head can stick through the hood sometimes.
- to connect the cape with the character you need to add a *Bone Contraint* in *Pose* mode to the cape's root bone, with the *body* bone of the *body* rig as a target. Make sure it's a *Bone Contraint*, not the *Object Contraint*. You can keyframe the *Influence* to 0 to simulate a take off the cape.
  [image: armature bone contraint]
- to make the *cape* armature move with the body armature in *Object* mode it must be a child of the *body* armature like you did. Disclaimer: I am not sure if this is 100% correct in relation to the *Bone Contraint: Armature*.

### Weight Paint

You've done already the arms and legs. You just need to assign the body and head to their bones. In *Edit* mode is the *Vertex Group Weights* overlay. If you enable it you can see the weight paint.

- use the <kbd>Assign</kbd> and <kbd>Remove</kbd> buttons to assign in *Edit* mode the *head* to the *head* vertex group and remove it from all other groups.
- do the same for the body and the ears.
- for the cape use *Parent, With Automatic Weights* and then assign the hood to the *Cape Root* bone:
  [image: weight paint]
- check if the *Armature* modifier of these objects is present
- make sure they are parented to the armature (*Object Properties > Relationship*)

### Picking Up the Knife

if you want to make the character interact with other objects like the knife make it an independent object.

- clear the parent
- remove the armature modifier if it's still there
- add an *Object Contraint* of type *Child Of*, set it to *body rig* & the *Hand.R* bone, and press the <kbd>Set Inverse</kbd>. With the *Influence* you can attach/detach it.

That's it. Happy animating!

Blend file: https://pasteall.org/blend/df35aa1718e44e6b8f79e00d84619120
(I've forgotten to add the root bone for the body rig in the example file).

Comment: Wow thank you so much! You went above and beyond with this! (I tried just following along with the directions you gave before downloading the blend you gave me!) A few things I will say are you didn't explain everything you did, (Unless I missed something in which I apologize) Never got to hear about adding armature mods to the ears and appendages, it worked out for the feet and arms but the ears wouldn't move with the head unless I was directly moving the head (As in wouldn't move with the body or root being the things I was moving around) And the belt wasn't moving at all! (1)

Comment: It was just a bit frustrating when I thought I had all the info (Which is why I'm so happy you gave the blend file for it! Another thing I want to point out is in the directions you gave, you said that parenting is ctrl+J when it's actually ctrl+P, luckily I knew what you meant though woops!

Again you did an amazing job and I'm so incredibly thankful for your help! People like you make it so much easier to deal with the parts of modelling that aren't as enjoyable! (2)

Comment: Oh sorry for the mistake and the omitted info. Yes, you need to parent the belt and potions to the armature (With Empty Groups) and then assign all verts to the *body* vertex group. Same for the ears and the *head* vertex group. Usually, I do the fixes and write them down at the same time. But this time it was a longer answer than I thought it would be. I've uploaded the file because I was already afraid that I had missed some information.  Glad you got it right and it helped you  :)