# Skin Clipping through Clothing

Tags: animation, mesh, topology

I have an issue with my character's skin clipping through the clothing I have added. My aim is to make clothing separate from the body and export the model and clothing to unity for game purposes. This means they can't all be one mesh.

I have some thin clothing that clips a *lot*. e.g. the leggings and gloves. But even the jumper is clipping and, as the gif and images show, it is a very thick jumper.

The clothing here is literally copied from the base mesh, only edited where it isn't appropriate for it to be skin-tight. Though even the skin-tight areas with identical topology clips. So far this model is only animated using Mixamo, so I am wondering if this is just going to be an inherent issue with how mixamo weight-paints multiple meshes in a single fbx. But if someone can see an inherent issue with what I am currently doing, or things I should try, I'd rather catch it now than after I'm already animating.

Here's an example of the clipping:

[image]

Here is the outline of the model and how far under the jumper it is:
[image]

Clipping on skin-tight leggings:

[image]

Legging and Legs Topology side-by-side
[image]

Comment: an easy way to fix it would be to delete this part of your skin, would it be a problem for your purpose?

Comment: My issue there is how would I make that work on a clothing-by-clothing basis in a game? e.g. swapping out the leggings for full length trousers, the jumper for a tank top, etc. Would I need to massively segment my characters body?

Comment: if you stayed within Blender there's a trick with the Mesh Deform modifier, see here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6s9H8xX7YA ... but as your question is about exporting to a game, I guess you can't use this trick. I hope someone will answer

Comment: Nice model! In Blender, you can use the *Mask* modifier to hide the skin that clips through the clothing. Another option is using a *Mesh Deform* modifier to create a cage as mentioned in the video linked by moonboots above. If you want to export the model into a game engine (Unity) and swap there the clothing it might be better to look for Unity related tutorials (https://youtu.be/hcJ5luBs_jw). "Swapping clothing", "interchangeable armor" and "character customization" are good keywords.

Comment: Royal Skies also has many videos about Blender and game characters like this one: https://youtu.be/UKPDWq3uxhY (the conclusion is to remove the skin under the cloth. This can be done by applying the Mask modifier when you export the model. For cloth simulations use the game engine's cloth simulation.)

Comment: The answer for this problem is, get rid of the skin underneath.  Yes, you can get rid of it on the basis of what clothing you put on-- set up a shader in Unity and a mask texture so you can send the shader a "clothing ID" and figure out what skin to clip().  Alternatives include corrective shapekeys, and weight painting alone might do it, but the best, most general answer is to get rid of the skin.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem when I animated the girl and her dress by cloth simulation and I find out, that the perfect answer is  **Weight Paint Transfer**.

The skin of your model is riged by armature and has weight.
So you can transfer weight of the skin to the clothes.
First select the skin, and holding SHIFT select the Cloth. The Cloth stand orange, in actve mode.
Go to Weight Paint, select Transfer Weights.
Down Left open window and
chose Source. By name. And that is it.
YouTube @RoyalSkies has video

Blender 2.82 : Rigged Character Weight Paint Transfer (In 60 Seconds!)

https://youtu.be/bR_Vke__voU

and the more detailed tutorial

How To Transfer Weights from one Mesh to Another - Blender 2.8
by Levonotion Studios

https://youtu.be/arXf5EV3H1c

Cheers!